# Multiple rows/columns timestamp, any way to make it easier?

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp, google-sheets-api

So, I wanted to know if there is easier way to do than using `(r.getRow() ==x)` and do multiple lines for rows?

It's only suppose to stamp on specific rows and in original sheets there is over 50 subjects and they all have their own rows for stamp.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    if (s.getName() == "spreadsheet1") {
      var r = s.getActiveCell();
      if (r.getRow() == 3) {//kuitattavat rivit
        var nextCell = r.offset (1, 0);
          if (nextCell.getValue() === "") {//tarkistaa solun onko tyhjä}
            nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("HH:mm");
          }
      }
      else {
      var r = s.getActiveCell();
        if (r.getRow() == 5) {//kuitattavat rivit
          var nextCell = r.offset (1, 0);
          if (nextCell.getValue() === "") {//tarkistaa solun onko tyhjä}
            nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("HH:mm");
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        var r = s.getActiveCell();
        if (r.getRow() == 7) {//kuitattavat rivit
          var nextCell = r.offset (1, 0);
          if (nextCell.getValue() === "") {//tarkistaa solun onko tyhjä}
            nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("HH:mm");
          }
        }
      }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to use an `onEdit(e)` trigger anyway, you can just reference the sheet name and range of `e` and check the row number from there using logical OR operator `||`.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.range.getSheet();
  if (s.getName() == "spreadsheet1") {
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    if (row == 3 || row == 5 || row == 7) {
      var nextCell = e.range.offset(1, 0);
      if (nextCell.getValue() === "") {
       nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("HH:mm");
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Sample:

[image]

References:

[Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

[logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)